# React-Native: Flatlist ScrollToPosition doesn't scroll to actual position

Tags: android, react-native

With flatList and rendering about 100 items or so. Once we use scrollToOffset that are outside the rendered zone, the scrollToIndex function will only bring you the last frame of the initially rendered items. Is this a limitation, or am I doing something wrong.

This can be fixed but setting the initialNumToRender to a very large number supporting 100+ items, but in this case the performance will suffer.

Current situation: 
We render 100 objects to place in the flatList. They are dynamic in size so using getItemLayout/ scrollToIndex is out of the question. When the user moves out of the page, and then comes back, we want the position to be maintained. But on Android, if it is an item very far down on the list, it won't maintain that position, and will put us at the end of the initial rendered position.

Version:
React-native: 0.44
React: 16.0.0-alpha.6

Answer (score 0):

I read that the only way to get this to work is to also use the `getItemLayout` prop. This will also improve perf for the flatlist. One thing to note, however, is that the rows need to have the same height in order for this to work.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout

Comment: yes, I was aware of that, and unfortunately we do not have the knowledge of the hight of each card so we were not able to implement it that way.